# RoR: destroy.js.erb not being run along with destroy action

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

My issue is that I expect on calling the destroy action of my swipe controller (which does work) that it would then call the javascript in the file app/views/swipes/destroy.js.erb. The idea being that on calling this file it will refresh my my-deck div and provide an updated web page. Unfortunately, although my destroy action is working, it doesn't seem to be calling the js correctly and I have to refresh the webpage to see that the item has been deleted.

Here are the relevant files, let me know if more info could be useful.

app/controllers/swipes_controller.rb

```
class SwipesController < ApplicationController

  def new


end
```

app/views/swipes/destroy.js.erb

```
$(".my-deck").alert("Foo");
```

app/views/my_deck/show.html.erb

```
<p> Welcome to my deck! </p>
<p> When this is working your right swiped events should appear beautifully below! </p>

<div class="my-deck">

</div>
```

app/views/my_deck/_my_deck.html.erb

```
    <p class="text-center">
  There are no items in your shopping cart.  Please <%= link_to "go back", home_path %> and add some items to your cart.
    </p>
 <% end %>
```

"app/views/my_deck/_card_row.html.erb"

```
<div class="well">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <h4><%= event_id %></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">



        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">

      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 text-right">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <%= link_to "Delete", myCard, { data: { confirm: "Are you     sure you wish to delete the product '#{myCard.event_id}' from your cart?"}, method: :delete, remote: true, class: "btn btn-danger" } %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Heres the output of my rails server when I click delete:

```
  Swipe Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "swipes".* FROM "swipes" WHERE "swipes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 48]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN

   (1.6ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered my_deck/_my_deck.html.erb (74.5ms)
  Rendered swipes/destroy.js.erb (79.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 91ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass)
  app/views/my_deck/_my_deck.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_my_deck__my_deck_html_erb___162867021113944140_70146212264540'
  app/views/swipes/destroy.js.erb:1:in     `_app_views_swipes_destroy_js_erb__359810691289434442_70146212224340'


  Rendered /home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered /home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.text.erb (8.9ms)
  Rendered /home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered /home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.5ms)
  Rendered /home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (14.6ms)
  Rendered /home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.3ms)
  Rendered /home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
  Rendered /home/tomos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (30.9ms)
```

If someone could help me figure out why app/views/swipes/destroy.js.erb is not running that'd be great. I'm following [this](https://richonrails.com/articles/building-a-shopping-cart-in-ruby-on-rails) tutorial.

Comment: remove the redirect_to line in the destroy method of your controller

Comment: Aww, that sounded like such a good shout but it didn't change anything. Thanks though

Comment: Yeah, I refresh and then it's gone (and I can verify this with the rails console) - everything seems fine except I can't get it to run the .js.erb file

Comment: You need to remove the redirect, since that will bypass the rendering of the corresponding view. Also, try removing the `alert` line in `destroy.js.erb`

Comment: I tried those but it doesn't make a difference

Comment: Where (which view) are you calling `destroy` from? That is the view that will be updated as per the js - if you are not already on the `app/views/my_deck/show` page, then nothing will happen, since there is no `my-deck` class to change.

Comment: Based on the error, looks like you need to define @myDeck in the destroy method in the swipes controller.

Comment: I added the view from which the destroy is called. I'm definitely on the /show page - basically my code uses two nested partials (as per the tutorial I mention at the end of the question)

Comment: Do not vandalize your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `destroy.js.erb`

```
$(".my-deck").alert("Foo");
$(".my-deck").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'my_deck/my_deck') %>");
```

renders `app/views/my_deck/_my_deck.html.erb`, that, in order, executes this line:

```
<% if @myDeck.size == 0 %>
```

Since you don't define `@myDeck` anywhere (neither in your controller's `destroy` action, nor in `destroy.js.erb`) this variable initializes to `nil`, which doesn't have any `.size` method, that causes error you have.

To fix the error you need either to properly initialize `@myDeck` var or to change your template so it won't access to uninitialized vars anymore (for example, remove line `$(".my-deck").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'my_deck/my_deck') %>");`).

Have a nice day!

Comment: I almost have a full solution now. I put the myDeck initialization into my destroy method and fixed up some other little errors to do with needing to put the partial addresses up an extra directory since otherwise it starts looking for /swipes/_my_deck.html.erb which doesn't exist. My only problem now is that when the _my_deck.html.erb refreshes, it lags by one item (i.e. because I reinitialize it in the destroy section that it uses that myDeck which doesn't get updated in time). Is there any way I can use the myDeck initialization in my my_deck_controller.js to apply to all controllers.

Comment: Sorry, it seems like a different bug, and I don't fully understand where do you initialize @myDeck and where it needs to get passed.

Comment: No I don't understand what I'm saying either

Comment: Thanks though Alexey, that was a really great spot

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when testing some ajax events, because something was missing on my action:

Here is what I added inside my destroy action:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js
end
```

Try change your destroy to:

```
def destroy

    @swipe = Swipe.find(params[:id])

    if @swipe.destroy
        redirect_to myDeck_path
    end

    respond_to do |format|
       format.js
    end

end
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Gave it a go but no luck, it gives exactly the same behaviour as before. Thanks!